# Show that the integers have infinite index in the additive group of rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know someone has answered this before but I didn't understand at all what the answer meant so I was hoping someone can answer it again please ?

Answer (score 0):

The quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite since for example the cosets $\frac{1}{n} + \mathbb{Z}$ ($n>0$) are pairwise distinct.

Answer (score 0):

The set of cosets is precisely the set of all sets of the form $\{k+x|k\in \mathbb Z\}$ where $x$ is of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime integers with $m<n$.

Comment: So how can you say that it has an infinite index

Comment: simply looking at the cosets of the form $\{k+\frac{1}{m}$ we already have an infinite amount, and these aren't all of them, so there is an infinite amount of cosets, and the index is the amount of cosets  in the quotient by definition